# Regex HTML or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

I need to make a regex validation in an input for the identification number,
but it has two formats (XX.XXX.XXX or X.XXX.XXX.XXX) and the X are only numbers.

I need a format which would set the dots automatically and detect which format it is.

Right now I got this:

```
[1-9]{1,2}[.][0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{3} 
and {1-9}[.][0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{3}
```

Comment: 'set the dots' -  does your validation input come with or  without dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the alternatives:

```
^([1-9]{2}[.][0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{3}|[1-9][.][0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{3})$
```

***Edit***

anchors added. These are essential here!

Comment: I did not know you could do that, im going to try

Comment: It doesn't match X.XXX.XXX.XXX

Answer (score 0):

I may want to use something like:

```
if (preg_match('/^([\d]{2}\.[\d]{3}\.[\d]{3}|^[\d]{1}\.[\d]{3}\.[\d]{3}\.[\d]{3})/', $mynumbers)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

It will match 2 sets of strings with digits:

`DD.DDD.DDD` or `D.DDD.DDD.DDD`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eG0dG5/2)

Regex Explanation:

```
^([\d]{2}\.[\d]{3}\.[\d]{3}|^[\d]{1}\.[\d]{3}\.[\d]{3}\.[\d]{3}?)

Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed) «^»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([\d]{2}\.[\d]{3}\.[\d]{3}|^[\d]{1}\.[\d]{3}\.[\d]{3}\.[\d]{3}?)»
   Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «[\d]{2}\.[\d]{3}\.[\d]{3}»
      Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «[\d]{2}»
         Exactly 2 times «{2}»
      Match the character “.” literally «\.»
      Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «[\d]{3}»
         Exactly 3 times «{3}»
      Match the character “.” literally «\.»
      Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «[\d]{3}»
         Exactly 3 times «{3}»
   Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «^[\d]{1}\.[\d]{3}\.[\d]{3}\.[\d]{3}?»
      Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed) «^»
      Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «[\d]{1}»
         Exactly once (meaningless quantifier) «{1}»
      Match the character “.” literally «\.»
      Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «[\d]{3}»
         Exactly 3 times «{3}»
      Match the character “.” literally «\.»
      Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «[\d]{3}»
         Exactly 3 times «{3}»
      Match the character “.” literally «\.»
      Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «[\d]{3}?»
         Exactly 3 times «{3}?»
```